# How do I link to a specific line number with "file:///" URLs?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, notepad++, php

The manual for Notepad++ says that you can use the **command line argument** -n123 to jump to the 123rd line of the specified file.

What about when the file is ***not*** opened from a command line, such as:

```
notepad++.exe -n123 "path to file.txt"
```

... but instead is a ***hyperlink*** in a local HTML document/context, such as:

```
<a href="file:///C:/PHP-dev/test.php">Line 123 of test.php</a>
```

? That will open test.php in Notepad++ on my system, but not going to any specific line. Since I *frequently* do this (I send myself HTML notifications for the enhanced PHP error log), it becomes a huge chore to always locate the lines manually. I wish I could do something like:

```
<a href="file:///C:/PHP-dev/test.php#n123">Line 123 of test.php</a>
```

... or:

```
<a href="file:///C:/PHP-dev/test.php#args=' . urlencode('-n123') . '">Line 123 of test.php</a>
```

... or *something* along those lines!

No matter what I try, and no matter how long I search, I find absolutely nothing related to this.

If I just make my PHP error logger function blindly run a bunch of terminal commands like the first example above, it will open a bunch of text files whenever there is an error, which is also not wanted. That would just create a mess in its own right and be highly disruptive of my "Notepad++ work environment".

Can you think of a way to solve this? Does file:/// really not have any support for this?

It would truly save me unimaginable amounts of time and efforts daily.

Comment: Not possible. In general, linking to local files will also definitely not open the associated application but instead “download” the file if the browser can’t display it.